# Reordering Boxplot in ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2, boxplot

I have the following test data, and would like to plot them in descending order somehow my codes doesn't produce the desired plot

[image: test_data_plot]

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>PAHs</th><th>Variable</th><th>Value</th></tr><tr><td>TB1</td><td>Nap</td><td>110</td></tr><tr><td>TB3</td><td>Nap</td><td>200</td></tr><tr><td>TB6</td><td>Nap</td><td>110</td></tr><tr><td>TB8</td><td>Nap</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>ND1</td><td>Nap</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>ND3</td><td>Nap</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>ND5</td><td>Nap</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND8</td><td>Nap</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT1</td><td>Nap</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT4</td><td>Nap</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>QT5</td><td>Nap</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT9</td><td>Nap</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>PT1</td><td>Nap</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>PT2</td><td>Nap</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT4</td><td>Nap</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB1</td><td>AcNP</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>TB3</td><td>AcNP</td><td>150</td></tr><tr><td>TB6</td><td>AcNP</td><td>70</td></tr><tr><td>TB8</td><td>AcNP</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>ND1</td><td>AcNP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND3</td><td>AcNP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND5</td><td>AcNP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND8</td><td>AcNP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT1</td><td>AcNP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT4</td><td>AcNP</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>QT5</td><td>AcNP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT9</td><td>AcNP</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>PT1</td><td>AcNP</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>PT2</td><td>AcNP</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>PT4</td><td>AcNP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB1</td><td>AcN</td><td>130</td></tr><tr><td>TB3</td><td>AcN</td><td>110</td></tr><tr><td>TB6</td><td>AcN</td><td>150</td></tr><tr><td>TB8</td><td>AcN</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>ND1</td><td>AcN</td><td>40</td></tr><tr><td>ND3</td><td>AcN</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND5</td><td>AcN</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND8</td><td>AcN</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>QT1</td><td>AcN</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT4</td><td>AcN</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>QT5</td><td>AcN</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT9</td><td>AcN</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>PT1</td><td>AcN</td><td>150</td></tr><tr><td>PT2</td><td>AcN</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>PT4</td><td>AcN</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>TB1</td><td>Fl</td><td>70</td></tr><tr><td>TB3</td><td>Fl</td><td>80</td></tr><tr><td>TB6</td><td>Fl</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB8</td><td>Fl</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND1</td><td>Fl</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND3</td><td>Fl</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>ND5</td><td>Fl</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND8</td><td>Fl</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>QT1</td><td>Fl</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT4</td><td>Fl</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>QT5</td><td>Fl</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT9</td><td>Fl</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT1</td><td>Fl</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT2</td><td>Fl</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>PT4</td><td>Fl</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB1</td><td>An</td><td>100</td></tr><tr><td>TB3</td><td>An</td><td>230</td></tr><tr><td>TB6</td><td>An</td><td>110</td></tr><tr><td>TB8</td><td>An</td><td>110</td></tr><tr><td>ND1</td><td>An</td><td>130</td></tr><tr><td>ND3</td><td>An</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>ND5</td><td>An</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>ND8</td><td>An</td><td>40</td></tr><tr><td>QT1</td><td>An</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>QT4</td><td>An</td><td>60</td></tr><tr><td>QT5</td><td>An</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT9</td><td>An</td><td>110</td></tr><tr><td>PT1</td><td>An</td><td>150</td></tr><tr><td>PT2</td><td>An</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>PT4</td><td>An</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>TB1</td><td>PhA</td><td>100</td></tr><tr><td>TB3</td><td>PhA</td><td>240</td></tr><tr><td>TB6</td><td>PhA</td><td>200</td></tr><tr><td>TB8</td><td>PhA</td><td>110</td></tr><tr><td>ND1</td><td>PhA</td><td>130</td></tr><tr><td>ND3</td><td>PhA</td><td>40</td></tr><tr><td>ND5</td><td>PhA</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>ND8</td><td>PhA</td><td>40</td></tr><tr><td>QT1</td><td>PhA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT4</td><td>PhA</td><td>70</td></tr><tr><td>QT5</td><td>PhA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT9</td><td>PhA</td><td>130</td></tr><tr><td>PT1</td><td>PhA</td><td>150</td></tr><tr><td>PT2</td><td>PhA</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>PT4</td><td>PhA</td><td>40</td></tr><tr><td>TB1</td><td>FlA</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>TB3</td><td>FlA</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>TB6</td><td>FlA</td><td>60</td></tr><tr><td>TB8</td><td>FlA</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>ND1</td><td>FlA</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>ND3</td><td>FlA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND5</td><td>FlA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND8</td><td>FlA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT1</td><td>FlA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT4</td><td>FlA</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>QT5</td><td>FlA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT9</td><td>FlA</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>PT1</td><td>FlA</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>PT2</td><td>FlA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT4</td><td>FlA</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>TB1</td><td>Py</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>TB3</td><td>Py</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>TB6</td><td>Py</td><td>60</td></tr><tr><td>TB8</td><td>Py</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>ND1</td><td>Py</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>ND3</td><td>Py</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND5</td><td>Py</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND8</td><td>Py</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT1</td><td>Py</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT4</td><td>Py</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>QT5</td><td>Py</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT9</td><td>Py</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>PT1</td><td>Py</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>PT2</td><td>Py</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT4</td><td>Py</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>TB1</td><td>BaA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB3</td><td>BaA</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>TB6</td><td>BaA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB8</td><td>BaA</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>ND1</td><td>BaA</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>ND3</td><td>BaA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND5</td><td>BaA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND8</td><td>BaA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT1</td><td>BaA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT4</td><td>BaA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT5</td><td>BaA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT9</td><td>BaA</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>PT1</td><td>BaA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT2</td><td>BaA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT4</td><td>BaA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB1</td><td>Chy</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB3</td><td>Chy</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB6</td><td>Chy</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB8</td><td>Chy</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND1</td><td>Chy</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>ND3</td><td>Chy</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND5</td><td>Chy</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND8</td><td>Chy</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT1</td><td>Chy</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT4</td><td>Chy</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT5</td><td>Chy</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT9</td><td>Chy</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT1</td><td>Chy</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>PT2</td><td>Chy</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT4</td><td>Chy</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB1</td><td>BpFlA</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>TB3</td><td>BpFlA</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>TB6</td><td>BpFlA</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>TB8</td><td>BpFlA</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>ND1</td><td>BpFlA</td><td>40</td></tr><tr><td>ND3</td><td>BpFlA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND5</td><td>BpFlA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND8</td><td>BpFlA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT1</td><td>BpFlA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT4</td><td>BpFlA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT5</td><td>BpFlA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT9</td><td>BpFlA</td><td>40</td></tr><tr><td>PT1</td><td>BpFlA</td><td>40</td></tr><tr><td>PT2</td><td>BpFlA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT4</td><td>BpFlA</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>TB1</td><td>BkFlA</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>TB3</td><td>BkFlA</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>TB6</td><td>BkFlA</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>TB8</td><td>BkFlA</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>ND1</td><td>BkFlA</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>ND3</td><td>BkFlA</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>ND5</td><td>BkFlA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND8</td><td>BkFlA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT1</td><td>BkFlA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT4</td><td>BkFlA</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>QT5</td><td>BkFlA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT9</td><td>BkFlA</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>PT1</td><td>BkFlA</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>PT2</td><td>BkFlA</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>PT4</td><td>BkFlA</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>TB1</td><td>BaP</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>TB3</td><td>BaP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB6</td><td>BaP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB8</td><td>BaP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND1</td><td>BaP</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>ND3</td><td>BaP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND5</td><td>BaP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND8</td><td>BaP</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>QT1</td><td>BaP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT4</td><td>BaP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT5</td><td>BaP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT9</td><td>BaP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT1</td><td>BaP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT2</td><td>BaP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT4</td><td>BaP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB1</td><td>dBahA</td><td>40</td></tr><tr><td>TB3</td><td>dBahA</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>TB6</td><td>dBahA</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>TB8</td><td>dBahA</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>ND1</td><td>dBahA</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>ND3</td><td>dBahA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND5</td><td>dBahA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND8</td><td>dBahA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT1</td><td>dBahA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT4</td><td>dBahA</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>QT5</td><td>dBahA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT9</td><td>dBahA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT1</td><td>dBahA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT2</td><td>dBahA</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT4</td><td>dBahA</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>TB1</td><td>IP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB3</td><td>IP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB6</td><td>IP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB8</td><td>IP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND1</td><td>IP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND3</td><td>IP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND5</td><td>IP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND8</td><td>IP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT1</td><td>IP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT4</td><td>IP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT5</td><td>IP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT9</td><td>IP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT1</td><td>IP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT2</td><td>IP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT4</td><td>IP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB1</td><td>BghiP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB3</td><td>BghiP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB6</td><td>BghiP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TB8</td><td>BghiP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND1</td><td>BghiP</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>ND3</td><td>BghiP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND5</td><td>BghiP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>ND8</td><td>BghiP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT1</td><td>BghiP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT4</td><td>BghiP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT5</td><td>BghiP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>QT9</td><td>BghiP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT1</td><td>BghiP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT2</td><td>BghiP</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PT4</td><td>BghiP</td><td>0</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)
library(scales)
scale_y_log2 <- function (...) 
{scale_y_continuous(..., trans = log2_trans())
}
alexa<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=T, sep=",")
require(reshape2)

alexa.m<-melt(alexa,id_var="PAHs")
alexa.m$PAHs<-factor(alexa.m$PAHs,rev(unique(alexa.m$PAHs)),ordered=TRUE) 
ggplot(alexa.m, aes(x=reorder(variable,-value),y=value))+scale_y_log2()+ 
 stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') + 
 geom_boxplot()+xlab(" ")+ ylab("PAHs concentration(µg/L)") +
  theme(axis.text.y   = element_text(size=11),
        axis.text.x   = element_text(size=11),
        axis.title.y  = element_text(size=11),panel.background = element_blank(), panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1))
```

Comment: welcome to SO. Please help us help you and kindly make your question reproducible/ https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: also please kindly clarify based on what values you would like to sort your boxplots "in descending order" - the median? Maximum values?

Comment: It is ok to have  maximum or median, i just want to have the plot in descending order so they are more comphrensible.

Comment: It is little bit difficult provide a working answer without seeing dataset. Please consider posting a reproducible example as @Tjebo highlighted. That said, you can summarize the results (by median or maximum) and use its order to re-order the variable (x-axis labels) as a factor. Much easier than trying to achieve reordering within `ggplot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plot is already in descending order - in means.

If you check `?reorder`, the default is to order by mean. 
You can specify how you want function you want to use to reorder the values of interest by `FUN`.

For example:
The line below reorders by median of value in an ascending manner.

```
aes(reorder(variable, value, FUN = median), value)
```

The line below reorders by max value in an ascending manner.

```
aes(reorder(variable, value, FUN = max), value)
```

For descending order, add a minus sign like you already did

```
aes(reorder(variable, -value, FUN = median), value)
aes(reorder(variable, -value, FUN = min), value)
```

Comment: Hi @Nomad420, reordering by max in ascending manner works fine but doesn't work for descending manner.

Comment: You are correct - a flaw in my logic. 
If we reorder by ```-value``` instead of ```value```, we have to sort by ```min``` instead of ```max```.
ie, The largest positive number becomes the most negative number.

Try ```aes(reorder(variable, -value, FUN = min), value)```